# Error imporing tensorflow in python 3.4 "Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime"

Tags: python, tensorflow

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py", line 61, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
ImportError: /opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2015.1/lib/lnx64.o/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.19' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "image_resize.py", line 10, in 
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py", line 24, in 
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py", line 72, in 
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py", line 61, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
ImportError: /opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2015.1/lib/lnx64.o/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.19' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so)

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#import_error

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

i am using ubuntu 14.4
and python version 3.4

Comment: How did you install TensorFlow? For Linux and Python 3.4 you may want to try this: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#python_34

Comment: thanks for your reply.

Comment: i tried your link. i am getting same error         @ Neal

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you installed Xilinx which includes an older version of libstdc++. If you remove it from your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, that should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu 14.4 with python 3.5. I run the following and the python3 shell imported tensorflow perfectly fine.

```
sudo -H pip3 install tensorflow
```